# PHP JavaScript - Redirect when a select is changed

Tags: javascript, php, html

```
 <select name="betrag" id="guitatype" onchange="test();">
     <?PHP            
        foreach($pscBetraege as $pscs) {
           echo'<option value="'.$pscs.'">'.$pscs.'</option>';
      }            
  ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
        function test(){
             if (document.getElementById("guitatype").value = "Paypal";) {
           window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
         } 
    }
         </script>
 </select>
```

I want that when the select id="guitatype" value is changed to "PayPal" the site redirects the user to ex: stackoverflow.com , but those scripts don't work.

[Print .png here](http://i.gyazo.com/1c5bf6a5f09c488de8c3f24644c7c9af.png)

Comment: It's == not = where you check for the value.

Comment: Please don't dump code into the comments @coderboi_89

Answer (score 2):

You need to close your select tag, and you have some syntax errors in your javascript. Also, there is no need to reselect the element with getElementById, simply pass the value into the function:

```
<select name="betrag" id="guitatype" onchange="test(this.value);">
<?php           
 foreach($pscBetraege as $pscs) {
 echo'<option value="'.$pscs.'">'.$pscs.'</option>';
 }            
 ?>
</select>


<script type="text/javascript">
function test(val){
    if (val == "Paypal") {
        window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing **==** insted of **=**

Change the code as,

```
if (document.getElementById("guitatype").value == "Paypal";) {
    window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
}
```